# Selenium Webdriver: Getting Nullpointerexception while reading an .xls file and unable to read it

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get data from the .xls file but when it tries to read sheet from .xls file, it throws nullpointerexception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at lib.ExcelDataConfig.getData(ExcelDataConfig.java:31)
>       at data.ReadData.main(ReadData.java:15)

Following is my code:

**1. ReadData.java**

```
public class ReadData {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
    ExcelDataConfig dc=new ExcelDataConfig(path+"\\file\\TestData.xls");

    String data=dc.getData("Sheet1", 0, 0);
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

}

**2.ExcelDataConfig.java**

```
public class ExcelDataConfig {

HSSFWorkbook wb;
HSSFSheet sheet;
public ExcelDataConfig(String filepath){

    try {
        File fl=new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fl);
        HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getData(String sheetName, int row, int col) {
    sheet=wb.getSheet(sheetName);//throws exception at 
    String data=sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();

    return data;
}

 }
```

Comment: Check if your constructor ExcelDataConfig initialized wb field properly, there is a possibility that wb could be null. You could add null check in getData() method.

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz Sroka for reply. But how can check that? could you help me with that?

Comment: use if(wb==null) { throw new IllegalStateException("wb not initialized"); }

Comment: Nope. wb is not null. still getting nullpointerexception :-(

Comment: Check the sheet variable if it is null or not because getSheet() method can return null if there is no sheet with name Sheet1 in provided file.

Comment: Ahh..Thank god..you saved my day @MateuszSroka. Sheet was getting null actually as name was varying in sheet. Thanks a lot for your time and help :-)

Comment: You also have declared 2 workbooks of same variable name `wb`. One as class member and other as constructor's  variable.  Of course this is not a cause of `nullPointerException` :)